# Mathematical modeling stackexchange

Tags: discussion

There is currently a proposal for a mathematical modeling stackexchange on Area51:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling?referrer=B5TWQ70QNWlDGxDR-o9vQA2

This is intended to have no overlap with physicsSE; questions that are on-topic on one site should be off topic on the other. With that said, the site is still in the definition phase, so it needs people to post suggested mathematical modeling questions that they would like to see answered in the future. These questions can then be voted on by others (a 5 vote limit) to decide what the site should be about.

This should help with any questions that are too experience based for MathSE and too mathematical or too localized for PhysicsSE

Comment: A note: It is perfectly OK for site topics to overlap, as long as one is not a subset of the other.

Comment: There already is a [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) beta. So why create another site?

Comment: Like Pulsar I see that as almost entirely a subset of SciComp.SE. The only possible exceptions would be for game-like models which are covered under GameDev.SE.

Comment: As I explained in the comments [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/10994/43086), this is **not** a duplicate of Computational Science. The only modeling questions allowed on SciComp (based on their help center) are those asking how to numerically solve for a particular quantity on a computer. There's quite a bit more to mathematical modeling than that, such as questions about modeling principles/model building, what models exist for a particular system, what approximations are valid, etc. None of those are on-topic on SciComp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consider supporting proposals of other SE science sites](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites)